# Can I paint over RedGard waterproof membrane?

Tags: bathroom, painting, paint

I am redoing the bathroom.  I just finished hanging the Durock around the 3-wall alcove tub.  My plan is to waterproof it with [RedGard](http://www.custombuildingproducts.com/ProductCatalog/SurfacePrep/WaterproofingAntiFractureMembranes/RedGard.aspx) before setting tile.

At the outside edges of the tub front (the two vertical parts of the tub on the "left" and "right" side that go from the tub deck down to the floor) I don't have enough room to place tile, but I am a bit worried about water splashing there.  Can I put a thin strip of Durock and put the RedGard on it, but then paint it with the normal latex wall paint?  Or should I cover the RedGuard in joint compound in this area (obviously I can paint over joint compound)?

I would hate to spend all this effort remodeling the bathroom just to get water damage along this thin strip by the tub if I just use drywall and paint it.

Comment: We don't want to tile all the way up to the ceiling in our shower, so I was wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you'd take the time to put tile there. You can cut tile fairly easily to fit.

If not, I imagine you can. I *think* I overlapped into the sheetrock area of my bath with redgard when I did it and the paint is fine, but I don't completely recall how far I took the RedGard. As long as you use a good primer, you should be OK, though.

Comment: Cutting tile is not so much the issue.  It is just a very narrow space about an inch wide.

Comment: We have the same. Seems to work fine. You don't need much room to attach tile.

Comment: Yep, just backbutter the piece of cut tile and stick it in place.

Comment: I just tiled it and it looks good and seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply thinset over the RedGard and prime and paint over that. Joint compound is reactivated when it absorbs water and can cause problems like mold and blistering or delamination of paint film.